# How to update a Github cloned repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-clone

I have created a repository on Github, and the cloned from my local machine and also push some code. I cloned that repository from a virtual online machine with the repository code, the problem is that I have already cloned it once, after that, I commited some changes from my local machine and tried to clone the repo online again to add that changes to my online repo, but I got this error:

```
fatal: destination path '' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

I don't know if there's another way to acomplish this, I'm pretty new to git and there's a lot yet to learn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `git pull` instead of using `git clone` a second time in your virtual machine. Make sure to `cd` into the repo folder on the virtual machine before you pull.

You only need to clone once. Every time after that you only need to pull new updates.

Comment: And is it enough with `git pull`? I'm doing it and it seems to be pulling the changes but somehow they don't update the older ones, I'm checking if I'm doing something wrong anyway.

Comment: Yes, `git pull` is enough to get the new edits from your repo in GitHub and apply those edits to the files in your clone. Can you be more specific with what you mean with "don't update the older ones"?

Comment: Basically in my last commit I added some files and delete a couple ones, but I'm not seeing that changes reflected in my proyect file (on my online machine): But i do see that commit in Github with all the changes

Comment: I already tried to `git reset` that last pull and then `git pull` again but nothing changes.

Comment: What output do you get from `git status`?

Comment: Solved, I basically delete the project and cloned it again, now `git pull` works great, I don't know what I was doing wrong, but anyway it's already solved, thanks!

Comment: New branches from original repo do not actually get updated with pull into the cloned repo, how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This error will show, when you try to clone a repo in a folder where a git repo **already exist** (`.git`-folder).

When you have `git clone` once your git repository, and you will update this repository, to be up to date on your local computer, you must do `git pull` to become the changes from the remote repository to your local computer.

#### Short explanation:

`git clone` - you download all files from this repository and the sourcetree from this repository

`git pull` - takes all changes from remote to your local computer